# saving segmented images from a number plate

Tags: matlab

hye everyone i m doing my project "automatic vechicle identification".i have to design software in matlab,i have done extraction of plate region ,segmentation of characters,...now i want to save these segmented characters so that i can further  recognize these character from a data base......any body can help me please feel free to write to me, thanks in advance

Comment: please ignore all cars marked "DX 234 AG".

Answer (score 1):

So if you have some data, `myData` then you can just issue a command `save myData` and you will have a new file in the current directory named `myData.mat`.  To load the data later, just type in `load myData` and then you will have a new variable in the workspace named `myData`.  There's lots more you can do with this, so you should check out `help save`.

Alternatively you could use a database.  I've never actually used a database in Matlab, but there seems to be plenty of information about how one would go about doing this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/database/ug/database.html